# Union-Find or DFS: which one is better to find connected component?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Union-Find and DFS could be both used to find connectivity. Which one is better in which condition?

Answer (score 57):

The union-find algorithm is best suited for situations where the equivalence relationship is changing, i.e., there are "Union" operations which need to be performed on your set of partitions. Given a fixed undirected graph, you don't have the equivalence relationships changing at all - the edges are all fixed. OTOH, if you have a graph with new edges being added, DFS won't cut it. While DFS is asymptotically faster than union-find, in practice, the likely deciding factor would be the actual problem that you are trying to solve.

tl;dr - Static graph? DFS! Dynamic graph? Union-find!

Comment: I don't understand why DFS won't cut it -- cant' you just add or remove edges from the adjacency lists (or adjacency matrix) and then just re-run DFS?

Comment: @user755921  Each new union/find operation using a smart union-find algorithm takes practically O(1) time. You can read more at https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/  This is much faster than "just re-run DFS"

Answer (score 22):

If the graph is already in memory in adjacency list format, then DFS is slightly simpler and faster (O(n) versus O(n alpha(n)), where alpha(n) is inverse Ackermann), but union-find can handle the edges arriving online in any order, which is sometimes useful (e.g., there are too many to fit in main memory).

Answer (score 8):

If the graph is already been given in the form of an adjacency list or matrix then DFS/BFS is more suitable but if the list of edges/relationship is given then its more suitable to use DSU(disjoint set), as if you would go for making graph from the edges then first you'll make the graph then go for dfs but by forming dsu you can directly calculate the number of components and number of nodes/edges in each component.