# Efficient connection grouping algorithm or implementation in python

Tags: python, algorithm, grouping

I'm looking for an efficient connection grouping (I'm not sure this is proper name..) algorithm or implementation by python.

For example, I have this nested list:

```
connection_data = [
   ...:     ["A", "B", "C"],
   ...:     ["B", "D"],
   ...:     ["A", "C"],
   ...:     ["E", "F"],
   ...:     ["C", "D"],
   ...:     ]
```

This data means each list in the nested list shows connections.
For example, the first connection `["A", "B", "C"]` means `A` and `B` and `C` are having connection each other.
The nested list has multiple connections information.

I would like to calculate connection groupings from a nested list.
For example, when I have the upper `connection_data`, I would like to get

```
grouped_connection = [
   ...:     ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
   ...:     ["E", "F"],
   ...:     ]
```

Because, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` have connections in these connection data in the `connection_data`: `["A", "B", "C"], ["B", "D"], ["A", "C"], ["C", "D"]`, `E` and `F` have connection by `["E", "F"]`.

To summarize my questions:

1. What is this type of problem called in general?
2. I think I can implement a many for-loop based solver. But is there any efficient algorithm or implementation in python for this type of problem?

Comment: I think this is relevant: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154368/union-find-implementation-using-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154368/union-find-implementation-using-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** This answer is actually ***slower*** than the union-find algorithm given by hilberts_drinking_problem. If all of the input connections are pairs (i.e. of size 2), the runtime of both algorithms is essentially the same. However, this is ***not*** the case for OP's question. See the comments for more details.

---

You can construct a graph where the nodes are lettered `A`, `B`, `C` ..., and place an undirected, unweighted edge between two nodes if the initial groupings dictate that they should be in the same group. Then, the final groups are the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) of the constructed graph. (This is the closest thing to what your problem is generally called.)

This can be done using a graph traversal algorithm, such as BFS or DFS, but if you don't want to code this up by hand, `networkx` can take care of everything once you've made the graph. You need to do a little bit of preprocessing on the groupings since some of them are of size greater than two, but otherwise `networkx` is well-suited for this problem:

```py
from itertools import combinations
import networkx as nx

groups = [
    ["A", "B", "C"],
    ["B", "D"],
    ["A", "C"],
    ["E", "F"],
    ["C", "D"],
]

G = nx.Graph()

# Handle initial groupings of size greater than two by iterating over
# each possible pair of letters in the group.
for group in groups:
    G.add_edges_from(combinations(sorted(group), 2))

# Result should look something like [['B', 'C', 'A', 'D'], ['F', 'E']],
# but the ordering may be nondeterministic.
print(list(list(group) for group in nx.connected_components(G)))
```

Comment: I suggest `from itertools import combinations` then you can replace your triple loop with `for group in groups: G.add_edges_from(combinations(sorted(group), 2))`

Comment: Also note that you can write `nx.connected_components` directly without knowing that it's in `nx.algorithms.components`. This has three advantages: you don't need to know where it is exactly; it's shorter and more readable; if in a future version, networkx is organized differently, your code won't break.

Comment: Also, personally when I read answers on StackOverflow, I really like to be able to see the output. So in this case I suggest adding the result `# [['E', 'F'], ['B', 'A', 'C', 'D']]` just below the final `print` statement.

Comment: I think union find is _the_ way to approach this problem, although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398101/union-find-or-dfs-which-one-is-better-to-find-connected-component) reference provides some relevant discussion.

Comment: @Stef Revised answer.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem IMO explaining it in terms of a graph is easier because you can easily break the problem down in terms of nodes, edges, and a standard graph algorithm. I don't think there's anything wrong with union-find though. (Someone in the discussion you linked noted that `union()` isn't an `O(1)` operation, but the inverse Ackermann function is bounded by a small constant in practice.)

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark The graph version has complexity proportional to the sum of squares of sizes of the groups (because a group of size k results in k(k-1)/2 edges). The union-find version has complexity proportional to the sum of sizes of the groups.

Comment: @Stef Ah, fair point. Normally the problem is formulated in a way where all the groups are of size 2, so this issue doesn't usually crop up.

Comment: I also added a clear note indicating that union-find is faster in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Networkx provides an implementation of a union find datastructure [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)] [[2](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/utils/union_find.html)] that solves this problem efficiently:

```
from networkx.utils.union_find import UnionFind

groups = [
    ["A", "B", "C"],
    ["B", "D"],
    ["A", "C"],
    ["E", "F"],
    ["C", "D"],
]

ds = UnionFind()
for gp in groups:
  ds.union(*gp)
for s in ds.to_sets():
  print(s)

# {'B', 'C', 'D', 'A'}
# {'E', 'F'}
```